# Apparently 1vw is not 0.5vw+0.5vw

Tags: css, viewport-units

So I need to make evenly spaced out elements for gallery but apparently 1vw =/= 2 * 0.5vw

```css
.galeriacontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 80vw;
  height: 75vh;
  max-height: 75vh;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
  left: 10vw;
  top: 12.5vh;
}
.itemframe {
  width: 19vw;
  max-width: 19vw;
  height: 24vh;
  max-height: 24vh;
  margin-left: 0.5vw;
  margin-top: 0.5vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeriacontainer">
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

So the gallery container is 80vw so if I want 4 divs evenly spaced out I do 80/4=20, 20-1=19, 1/2=0.5, right? I can't understand why it displays so strangely.

EDIT: My question is how to make it behave the way it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be reasonably even, but it's not a very good solution, just fine-tuned sizes and margins.

```css
.galeriacontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 80vw;
  height: 75vh;
  max-height: 75vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
  left: 10vw;
  top: 12.5vh;
}
.itemframe {
  width: 19.25vw;
  height: 23.75vh;
  margin-left: 0.6vw;
  margin-top: 0.95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeriacontainer">
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting 0.5vw margin on the left side, but forgot the equivalent margin-right:

```css
.galeriacontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 80vw;
  height: 75vh;
  max-height: 75vh;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
  left: 10vw;
  top: 12.5vh;
}
.itemframe {
  width: 19vw;
  max-width: 19vw;
  height: 24vh;
  max-height: 24vh;
  margin-left: 0.5vw;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  margin-top: 0.5vh;
  bottom: 0.5vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeriacontainer">
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div><div class="itemframe">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now there is bigger spacing between the cells than the container. And I derped... That's wrong snippet... going to test something and then post back

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer for helping me to figure it out. I'm too tired and derped really hard
EDIT: well... I would need 15 rep to do that

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was indeed the wrong snippet and I just derped by dividing what I deduced from the element width instead of 19*4=76, 80-76=4, 4/5(number of spaces between these elements, including the outer ones)=0.8

```
.itemframe {
width: 19vw;
max-width: 19vw;
height: 24vh;
max-height: 24vh;
margin-left: 0.8vw;
margin-top: 0.75vh;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
float: left;
overflow: hidden; }
```